# Wordpress, плагин, ajax, правильная реализация

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Задача:
Создать "плагин" на WP, который будет генерировать форму и отображать её на определённых страницах.
Форма, при помощи AJAX, будет получать нужные данные из БД, в зависимости от ранее заполненных пунктов этой формы.

Вопрос:
Как правильно реализовать?

Если в главном файле плагина создать хук wp_ajax_(action) с функцией, сделать подключения JS, то всё работает.

Не получается сделать ajax, если весь код выше, добавить в главный файл при помощи include. Выскакивает ошибка 400

Код в главном файле плагина:

```
include_once UrlPlugin.'addEditVote/AddEditVote.php';
```

Файл AddEditVote.php(всё, что ниже, располагается в отдельной папке):

```
// при срабатывании хука действия wp_ajax с экшеном hello, выполняется функция say_hello
add_action( 'wp_ajax_hello', 'say_hello' );
function say_hello() {
    echo "УРАААААААААААА!";
    wp_die();
}

// при хуке действии wp_enqueue_scripts, вызываем функцияю, которая зарегистрирует JS код обработчика AJAX и выставил её после jQuery
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxAddEditVote', plugins_url('ajaxAddEditVote.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null);
    // До вывода JS, вызванного wp_enqueue_script, выводим JS объект с какими либо значениями
    wp_localize_script('ajaxAddEditVote', 'localizePlugin', array(
        'ajaxURL' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));
});
```

И сам JS файл ajaxAddEditVote.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    var data = {
        action: 'hello'
    };
    jQuery.post(localizePlugin.ajaxURL, data, function (response) {
        alert('Получено с сервера: ' + response);
    });
});
```

Как это сделать правильно (последовательность подключения файлов и запросов, ознакомился с кучей тем и в итоге полная путаница =). спасибо) ?

Answer (score 1):

В целом всё сделано правильно, и подтверждением этому является работа при включении кода в основной файл плагина.

Ошибка при выносе в include заключается в том, что вы используете магическую константу `__FILE__`, которая указывает на **текущий** файл кода. При выносе кода `__FILE__` получает другое значение, и `wp_enqueue_script()` не запускает ваш скрипт вообще.

Ещё надо бы добавить nonce, согласно [руководству](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html). Сейчас ваш сайт, в теории, можно заставить выполнить серверный код `say_hello()`, послав POST-запрос извне.

**UPDATE**

Из комментариев видно, что вы вынесли файл скрипта js в ту же папку, что и код php. В этом случае скрипт будет запускаться, всё правильно. Ошибка 400 вызвана наверняка тем, что у вас отсутствует строка

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_hello', 'say_hello' );
```

При попытке выполнить ajax запрос от незалогиненного пользователя, вызывается хук `wp_ajax_nopriv_hello`. При отсутствии такого хука WordPress завершает выполнение с кодом 400. Смотрите строку 101 в файле `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.

Comment: Перепроверил ещё раз, в коде страницы, js, подключенный при помощи wp_enqueue_script, присутствует и перед ним располагается  wp_localize_script. Пусть до файлов верный. Не совсем понял как именно тогда сделать? А nonce обязательно изучу и сделаю, но как только этот вопрос пойму

Comment: А я не могу ответить, как надо, не видя путей к вашим файлам.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.